# CKEDITOR default tabble width

Tags: ckeditor

How do i change the default width of the tables in CKEditor, without doing it manualy in the dialog?

For example, the default is 500, and i want it to be 400.

Regards,
Elkas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I programmatically set default table properties for CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464395/how-do-i-programmatically-set-default-table-properties-for-ckeditor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the answer.

In the plugins folder, look for the table folder and table.js.
Do a litle search by the number "500" (it will be near a id:txtWidth) and change it to the value you want.

Pay attention because on the top of the file there is a minWidth.

Thanks for you're answer guys.

Regards,
Elkas

Comment: The problem of doing it that way is that you must remember to apply the change whenever you upgrade CKEditor. It's much better to write a little plugin that adjust the default values that you want and customize CKEditor without changing any of its core files: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Default_Field_Values

Comment: Updating the vendor code is not a goow way, as @AlfonsoML mentioned.

Comment: @milkovsky I agree. But that was the solution that I added at that time (really a long time ago) and left an annotation in the documentation. I think the library has more options nowadays but I'm not sure because I'm not working on BackOffice software anymore.

Answer (score 1):

For CKEditor 4, you can define a default width in your config (this info from the CKEditor forums). Open config.js and paste this at the end of it, replacing '100%' with your desired default width:

```
// http://ckeditor.com/comment/129258#comment-129258
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
    // interested in (the "Table" dialog).
    if ( dialogName == 'table' ) {
        // Get a reference to the "Table Info" tab.
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        txtWidth = infoTab.get( 'txtWidth' );
        txtWidth['default'] = '100%';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'the dialog'.

Using javascript code...

```
config.width = 850;
config.width = '75%';
```

I found this in the docs.

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Editor_Size

Is this any help?

Comment: Nope mate. Let me put a print screen here http://cl.ly/0p1t0a3Y3m3Y231l3h0H That "500" i want it to pass to 400 because all tables are 400px. And there are a lot of tables. Alter 1 by one seems a litle bit (long) "slow".

Comment: I found the answer. Look for the file table.js and change the default value near the id:txtWidth (its 500 by default) and assign the value you want. I'll post a answer to my question after 8 hours. =)

Comment: Ah beat me to it. Where did you find that answer?

Comment: I'll post the answer after you're mate :) I digged in the CKEditor's javascript files.