# How do I programmatically set default table properties for CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to set up the default properties of table that is created inside CKEditor.

For example is there a way to make sure that the attribute border is 0 not 1, or the width is by default set to 100%.

Comment: I find this question and answer very clear.  Not sure why this was closed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here you go. `dialogDefinition` event solves the problem:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if ( dialogName == 'table' ) {
        var info = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

        info.get( 'txtWidth' )[ 'default' ] = '100%';       // Set default width to 100%
        info.get( 'txtBorder' )[ 'default' ] = '0';         // Set default border to 0
    }
});

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

More to read:

- [This official guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_dialog_windows) will help you playing with dialog API (also with *devtools* plugin).
- [*Devtools* plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/devtools) is helpful when looking for IDs and elements in CKEditor dialogs.

Have fun!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed (still works in CKEditor 4).  The links you provided are dead, but the code example you provided was spot on (I wasn't able to find updated examples in the CKEditor 4 source, sorry).  Thanks!

Comment: 100% helpful on that above config. I found that http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Field_Names helped me configure the code to meet my needs.  devTools plugin was extra helpul in identifying the field names.

Comment: I updated links so they're alive back again and compatible with CKEditor 4.

Comment: This event is being fired when the table button is clicked in the toolbar, but not when you right click a table and choose "Table properties".

Comment: That dialogDefinition is never called to me. I tryed everything. It still works?

Comment: @mattalxndr I'm not sure why you'd want this to fire on Table Properties, I would think it should just remember what previously set? In any case, the Table Properties is actually a separate `dialogName` value which is `tableProperties`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make changes to the table options when the table is first created AND when the table properties are edited later, then you need to also target **'tableProperties'** in addition to 'table' as seen below:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
var dialogName = ev.data.name;
var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

  if ( dialogName == 'table' || dialogName == 'tableProperties' ) {
      var info = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

      info.get( 'txtWidth' )[ 'default' ] = '100%';       // Set default width to 100%
      info.get( 'txtBorder' )[ 'default' ] = '0';         // Set default border to 0
  }
});

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

This is from @DanH comments from the @oleq answer. But I thought it's worth putting into it's own answer since I overlooked this the first time I was making this change.