# CKEditor. Open image properties window with a default value

Tags: ckeditor

I've been looking at the API and I can not figure out how to open the image dialog with a default url. I use the `execCommand` function, as follows:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
editor.execCommand ('image');
```

This works fine, but I want to give some value. I tested with:

```
editor.execCommand ('image', {
   url: myrURL,
});
```

It does not work though. Please, I need help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programatically set default table properties for CKEditor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464395/how-do-i-programatically-set-default-table-properties-for-ckeditor)

Answer (score 2):

To set default value, you got to use the `dialogDefinition` event to modify dialog fields (see this answer: [How do I programatically set default table properties for CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464395/how-do-i-programatically-set-default-table-properties-for-ckeditor/12477003#12477003)).

To change the value dynamically:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'devtools', // useful for dialog development
    on: {
        dialogShow: function ( evt ) {
            var dialog = evt.data;

            if ( dialog.getName() == 'image' )
                dialog.setValueOf( 'info', 'txtUrl', 'http://foo.com' );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Then, to be tested with the API, I can not do what I want, which is to update the URL field value "dialog Image" dynamically, with the api get update the default value, but you need to refresh the page every time I want to change the field value.

Comment: A year later I wanted to thank you for this.  A brief foray into the world of CKEditor has been made briefer by this answer.  Thanks.