# CKEditor Dialog, hook to fire before the dialog pops up

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a dialog whose contents is populated by parsing the DOM of the current page. I've tried two things, neither of which are exactly correct:

1. `CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition',  ...` : This method works for the FIRST time the dialog is opened, but subsequent openings use the cached dialog definition, so any changes to the DOM don't show in the dialog contents.
2. `dialog.on('show', ...` : This method gets fired every time the dialog is shown, but it seems it gets fired AFTER the contents of the dialog have already been calculated.

So my question is: Is there a hook or some other method that I can use which will fill in the contents *every time the dialog opens*? Thanks!

**Edit**

Here is a basic example of what I have now, which does not work — the "No embeds" message doesn't show up in the dialog.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('embeds', {
  init: function(editor) {
    editor.on('dialogShow', function(event) {
      var dialog           = event.data,
          dialogDefinition = dialog.definition;

      if(dialog.getName() != "EmbedsDialog") return;
      var main   = dialogDefinition.getContents('main');

      main.add({
        type  : 'html',
        html : "<strong>There are no embeds yet! Add them below.</strong>"
      });
    });


    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('EmbedsDialog', function (instance) {
      return {
        title : 'Embeds',
        minWidth : 550,
        minHeight : 200,

        contents: [{
          id: "main",
          elements: []
        }],
      }; // return
    });

    editor.addCommand('Embeds',
      new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('EmbedsDialog', {
        allowedContent: 'a[*](*)'
      })
    );

    editor.ui.addButton('Embeds', {
      label     : 'Embeds',
      command   : 'Embeds',
      toolbar   : 'embeds'
    });
  } // init
}); // add
```

Comment: Use [`dialogShow`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-dialogShow) event (see: [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616605/ckeditor-open-image-properties-window-with-a-default-value/17616731#17616731), [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsPr8/)).

Comment: @oleq See my edit. The behavior is the same as when I tried `dialog.on('show' ...`