# CKEditor: set value of an input field in dialog window of plugin "image"

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can i get instances of plugin dialog window contents elemets to manipulate its for example set the value of an input field in dialog window of plugin "image"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to retrieve the native DOM element of a field (already opened dialog):

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().getContentElement( 'info', 'txtUrl' ).getInputElement().$
```

To dynamically set field's value when the dialog is shown, please refer to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616605/ckeditor-open-image-properties-window-with-a-default-value/17616731#17616731).