# Dynamically change ckeditor dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, ckeditor

I'm trying to modify the contents of a dialog field based on another field. I've tried the `replace` method, but I'm throw this error: `The editor instance "edit-body-und-0-value" is already attached to the provided element.` 
The basic goal is to add a class to the table. Using the table dialog I figured if I could fill in the `advCSSClassess` default value, then replace the editor, I'd now have a dialog in with the class attached.

Here's my plugin code:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if ( dialogName === 'table' ) {
        var tableProperties = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        var advancedTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'advanced' );
        var classField = advancedTab.get( 'advCSSClasses' );
        classField['default'] = 'stackable';
        tableProperties.add({
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 'stackTable',
            label: 'Make table responsive',
            'default': false,
            onClick: function( button ) {        
                classField[ 'default' ] = 'stackable';
                var thisEditor = CKEDITOR.instances;
                CKEDITOR.replace('edit-body-und-0-value', thisEditor);
            }

        });

    }
});
```

I've been able to hack it in like this in the click handler, but that doesn't seem sustainable.:

```
var classInput = $("label:contains('Stylesheet Classes')").attr('for');
$('#' + classInput).val('stackable');
```

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616605/ckeditor-open-image-properties-window-with-a-default-value/17616731#17616731) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464395/how-do-i-programatically-set-default-table-properties-for-ckeditor/12477003#12477003) for reference.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Since this question got a new request, here's the code that I ended up with. This is old enough that I can't remember the details, but I hope this helps.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
var dialogName = ev.data.name;
var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
if ( dialogName === 'table' ) {
  var tableProperties = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
  tableProperties.add({
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 'stackTable',
    label: 'Make table stackable on mobile. Does not work with header row.',
    'default': false,
    onClick: function( button ) {
      var classInput = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().getContentElement('advanced', 'advCSSClasses').getElement().$;
      $('#' + classInput.id).find('input').val('sy-stacktable');
    }
  });
}
});
```