# how to override ckeditor 4 image dialog?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {

   var dialogName = ev.data.name;
   var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
   console.log(ev);
    if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {

        console.log(dialogDefinition);
    }
});
```

I try to customize current existing image dialog, I wrote my code under ckeditor/plugin/dialog/dialogDefinition.js, when I run the code nothing log out. how to trigger my code? thanks.

Comment: Define it in your code, i.e. next to `CKEDITOR.replace`. `dialogDefinition.js` isn't where you should put it. See my previous answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464395/how-do-i-programatically-set-default-table-properties-for-ckeditor/12477003#12477003, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133800/how-do-i-customize-a-ckeditor-4-2-builtin-plugin-like-links/18142374#18142374.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer :
[Replace ceeditor file uploader](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29)

something like this :

[image: Browsing]
[image: Ckeditor Uploader]