# CKEditor: Customizing the Table Dialog Window

Tags: ckeditor

I am using the CKEditor module for Drupal7.
I want to customize the Table dialog window.
I saw this thread, But I am not clear where to add the code that @oleq added.
Here is the URL: [Set default table properties for CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464395/how-do-i-programatically-set-default-table-properties-for-ckeditor)

In what file should I add the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the regular ckeditor module (ie not through wysiwyg module), then you can just add it to the bottom of:

```
sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor.config.js
```

If you're using wysiwyg module and ckeditor library, then it's more complicated, and I'll post it as a separate question since a few people have asked this.