# How do I change default table properties like width for ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I would like to change the default table width for CKeditor. I read a lot about this subject, and tried to use this code to override table width:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

  if (dialogName == 'table') {
    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
    txtWidth = infoTab.get('txtWidth');
    txtWidth['default'] = '';
  }
});
```

But it didn't change anything, the width is still the default one.

Am I missing something? Have I forgotten something?

Thank you for your help

Comment: LOOK AT following link http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/How-set-standard-table-width-100

Comment: Thank's, but I already did what's written (create a folder for my plugin, create a plugin.js in it and paste the code), and it's still not working..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programatically set default table properties for CKEditor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464395/how-do-i-programatically-set-default-table-properties-for-ckeditor)

Comment: @oleq, I read this page, this is where I got the code. But for some reason it's not working, that's why I was wondering if I was missing something?

Comment: "But for some reason" – no data, no diagnosis. jsFiddle? Error log? Anything?

Comment: That's the problem, I have no error. I put the code in my js file:
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     //code
     });
but nothing happens