# how can remove ckeditor image tab info?

Tags: ckeditor

my ckeditor version : 4.3.5

it's very difficult customizing.

i want to cutumize [image info] just like (1) style.

- URL input include  Upload file select.
- remove send to server button.

or.. (2) style :: just remove tab[image info] and [send server button]

but i can't search these info. T^T plz help me.

i want to import image for my question describe. but i need 10 repution;
my question images link.

[image] : https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-fDpngTmZ9uw/U3mmOZiNA3I/AAAAAAAAABE/_Zoom5BOCJk/w958-h671-no/qna.png

---

soled

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {

   var dialogName = ev.data.name;
   var def = ev.data.definition;

   if ( dialogName == 'image2' ) {                      
       def.removeContents('info'); // info tab remove
       def.getContents('upload').remove('uploadSubmit');
   } 
 });

 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' ,
     {
        toolbar: 'Full',
         filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/editor/imgsave.do' // import img to server (java)
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead

```
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:info;image:Link;image:advanced';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dialogDefinition`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-dialogDefinition) event. See these answers ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464395/how-do-i-programatically-set-default-table-properties-for-ckeditor/12477003#12477003), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133800/how-do-i-customize-a-ckeditor-4-2-builtin-plugin-like-links/18142374#18142374)) and the [official how-to](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_dialog_windows) to know more.